# How to handle multiple invalid events being fired from collection.create() in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling, backbone-events

I am adding a model using the collection.create method.  I have over-ridden the model.validate method and the error window pops up I get the correct error messages.

Everything seems to work great until I click the save button a third of fourth time.  The invalid event gets fired for every previous invalid model.  I noticed the collection did not clean up after itself when the invalid event fired so I added the line model.collection.pop() hoping that would solve it.

The invalid event is still fired off n number of times.  N being the number of times I have attempted to create a new model until I reload the app.  I found that I should only display the error message if the model being passed in has a collection object on it.  And now everything works but this seems a bit janky.

I tried adding model.stopListening() inside the invalid event method.  No luck though.  I assume this has something to do with me not completely cleaning up these partial or invalid models.

```
createNewAsset: (event) ->
 @collection.on "invalid", (model, error) =>
      console.log "invalid fired"
      unless model.collection is undefined
        errView = new MyApp.Views.Error(collection: error)
        $("body").append(errView.render().el)
        model.collection.pop()

 @collection.on "sync", ->
   Backbone.history.navigate("assets", true)

 @collection.create 
   name: @$el.find("#new_asset_name").val()
```

**Clarification Update**:

The above code works for the end user, but I have some zombie models or collections firing off n number of events.  N being the number of times the user has clicked the save button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is that you have stray models, your problem is that you're binding a new anonymous `"invalid"` callback to the collection every time `createNewAsset` is called.

You should just bind your `"invalid"` and `"sync"` handlers once in `initialize`:

```
initialize: ->
  # You could still use anonymous functions here.
  @listenTo(@collection, 'invalid', @bad_model)
  @listenTo(@collection, 'sync',    @synced)
  #...

bad_model: (model, error) ->
  console.log('invalid fired')
  #...

synced: ->
  Backbone.history.navigate('assets', true)
```

And then your `createNewAsset` becomes simply this:

```
createNewAsset: (event) ->
  @collection.create
    name: @$('#new_asset_name').val()
```

I also switched your `@$el.find()` to [`@$()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) which is a standard built in short cut for `@$el.find`.